# How does UIWebview do its rendering in iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I have been using `UIWebView` to render file formats such as Keynote, Pages, Numbers, PPT, etc. Also, I tried accessing the various document attributes via `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` such as title, width, height, innerHTML, etc. and web view returns valid values for these.

So, my question is, how does UIWebView actually work? Does it convert everything to HTML before rendering? How does it return attributes such as innerHTML for non-html files?

Comment: Have you looked at the open source portions (WebKit)?

Comment: Thanks David! That is a good suggestion. I will have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be crazy for Apple to convert most formats to HTM.

Comment: Thanks! Then how does it return properties such as innerHTML even for PPT files? It has perfectly valid divs, paras, etc. Generating HTML code for other file types should be equally tedious.

Comment: Thanks! But then my question still holds. I too have the same doubts as you do.

Comment: I don't know at the time of wrinting, but this answer is currently outdated (and now wrong), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971969/ios-library-to-convert-powerpoint-presentations-into-images for up to date information

Answer (score 2):

The various formats you listed are most likely rendered by Webkit plug-ins.

Check out the documentation at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/WebKitPluginTopics.html. Plug-ins can also be written to allow Objective-C methods to be called from a scripting environment. It is possible that this would allow attributes such as innerHTML to be returned.

I have not actually developed any of these plug-ins but it does appear to allow UIWebView to be extended to render formats such as PPT and also to expose attributes. Based on this I do not believe that content is being converted to HTML but instead is custom drawn but exposes attributes such as width, height, etc through the plug-in.