# IOS library to convert powerpoint presentations into images

Tags: ios

after a lot of searching and still searching, i'm unable to find the way to extract the slides out of powerpoint presentations. Need help, if they know anything related this or have implemented such thing, source code will be great or any reference link will also work. I have been using QLPreviewController, but i failed to override it.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure whether this is still required. but anyways, this is how I have implemented

(1) Use `UIWebView` to display the content of the PPT. The well formed (!) HTML allows you to parse it. Get the html using

```
NSString *htmlContent = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

(2) Count the number of  `div class = 'slide` to get the slide count

(4) You need to parse the HTML to get the styles and `div` using the below code

(5) Get all the styles

```
- (NSString *)getStyles:(int)slideCount forView:(UIWebView *)view {

    NSString *getElementByTag = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *allStyles = [[NSString alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
        getElementByTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('style')[%d].innerHTML", i];
        NSString *style =  [[view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:getElementByTag] stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
        allStyles = [allStyles stringByAppendingString:style];
    }

    allStyles = [@"<style type='text/css'>" stringByAppendingString: allStyles];

    return [allStyles stringByAppendingString:@"</style>"];
}
```

(6) Concatenate all the styles from step 5 with `div` tag content. Define a `NSMutableArray` variable to to store all slides with styles for future reference. Define `NSMutableArray *slides` to store all the slides

```
- (void)makeSlides:(int)slideCount forView:(UIWebView *)view {

    self.slides = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
        NSString *slideBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByClassName('slide')[%d].innerHTML", i];
        NSString *div = [view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:slideBody];

        NSString *slide = [self.slideStyles stringByAppendingString:div];
        [self.slides addObject:slide];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful insight: it was not obvious that the webview actually converted powerpoint documents (and pdf, doc, ecc) into plain html! Still the possibility that this schema might change between versions strongly limits the exploitability of this feature: did you found any reliable technical documentation stating that the html will maintain backward compatibility (or at least do you have some first hand experience, e.g.: you used this feature since iOs4.x and didn't notice any change)?

Comment: Thanks Rick77. you are right. Any internal change in the iOS library will definitely make this approach useless. I just went through the innerHTML content and designed this. I did not find any other documentation. I tested this approach from ios5.0 through ios6.1 and this worked.

Comment: is there any possibility to get hyperlink from presentation slide?

Comment: Many thanks for the code snippet and suggestion for parsing out each slide. I had no idea it converted ppt files to html when it displayed in an UIWebView. I've expanded on your code and setup a full sample code that generates UIImage thumbnails each slide in a ppt file. Code is here: https://github.com/adamwulf/PowerPointToUIImage

Comment: I am not getting wellformed HTML content from excel sheet by using NSString *htmlContent = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"]; So what I do wrong in that ? plz help to get it.

Comment: Do you know about how to convert word(doc) to pdf .? ...please tell me..Thanks

Comment: Do you have any idea if we can get page numbers of word (doc) file, the way we are getting number of slides for PPT?

Comment: I think the page numbers are generated based on the page properties (top, left, right and bottom margin). I have not found the page number as a separate entity in the HTML generated by UIWebView

Comment: @adam.wulf : the given example works for .ppt and pptx, but not for .key file. Any idea about it ?  The below code gives slideCount = 0                            int slideCount = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('slide').length"] intValue];

Comment: @MansiPanchal last I remember the .key wasn't getting translated into HTML, or wasn't translated into something I could parse for slide count/bounds. that may have changed recently, but at the time I could only get it to work w/ powerpoint.

Comment: Update July 2017: This approach still works with the latest iOS