# Controlling Powerpoint presentations in iOS

Tags: ios, powerpoint

I'm making an iOS app that should open powerpoint files and display them with navigation controls. The navigation controls must be custom and more importantly I need to be able to control the preview programatically (next slide, previous slide) and disable navigation through scrolling/swiping.

So far I've looked into Quick Look, but it seems to only be able to preview a presentation in a vertical scrolling fashion with no means to control it. I've also looked into ways to convert a PPT to HTML5 ([this thread for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971969/ios-library-to-convert-powerpoint-presentations-into-images)) but as you can see it's not futur proof. I might use this solution if there is no other way, but in the meantime I'd be glad if anyone who has had to deal with a similar situation previously, or has the necessary knowledge, can point me towards a solution for loading a PPT and displaying it with custom navigation. Another possible way would be to split the PPT into images. I would be totally fine with that (I don't care about animations), but I don't know of a way to get the slide images yet.

Thanks for your help