# How to convert (.doc,.xls,.ppt) to pdf using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, quartz-core

I can able to implement the annotation on pdf file and export it.

But in the case of doc,xls and ppt i couldn't able to apply the annotation using objective c ?

So i had plan to convert the (.doc,.xls,.ppt) files to pdf format.

Using UIKit or Quartz framework possible to implement ?

Comment: It's possible, of course, but it's a serious amount of work.

Comment: @Droppy Thanks for your suggestion. . Can you please suggest any of apple methods or examples ?

Comment: Do you understand the issues to overcome?

Comment: Yes i can understand .. But i don't know how to start up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with google docs API.

I have implement [this](https://gist.github.com/kinlane/922855).

Just try it it is very easy to implement...

Second Option : Use following, I found it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971969/ios-library-to-convert-powerpoint-presentations-into-images/18129059#18129059).

---

(1) Use `UIWebView` to display the content of the PPT. The well formed (!) HTML allows you to parse it. Get the html using

```
NSString *htmlContent = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

(2) Count the number of  `div class = 'slide` to get the slide count

(4) You need to parse the HTML to get the styles and `div` using the below code

(5) Get all the styles

```
- (NSString *)getStyles:(int)slideCount forView:(UIWebView *)view {

    NSString *getElementByTag = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *allStyles = [[NSString alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
        getElementByTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('style')[%d].innerHTML", i];
        NSString *style =  [[view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:getElementByTag] stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
        allStyles = [allStyles stringByAppendingString:style];
    }

    allStyles = [@"<style type='text/css'>" stringByAppendingString: allStyles];

    return [allStyles stringByAppendingString:@"</style>"];
}
```

(6) Concatenate all the styles from step 5 with `div` tag content. Define a `NSMutableArray` variable to to store all slides with styles for future reference. Define `NSMutableArray *slides` to store all the slides

```
- (void)makeSlides:(int)slideCount forView:(UIWebView *)view {

    self.slides = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
        NSString *slideBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByClassName('slide')[%d].innerHTML", i];
        NSString *div = [view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:slideBody];

        NSString *slide = [self.slideStyles stringByAppendingString:div];
        [self.slides addObject:slide];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Roman C, For guidance. I am changing it

Comment: down voting because you just copied and pasted another stackoverflow answer. If you answer is just links then its not an answer and should go under comments.

Comment: Thanks Sam Budda. But i was suggested to not to post link only by stack overflow. Thats why i have pasted the whole answer. By the way i have confessed that i found this from another answer before pasting it.

Comment: You should not down vote it just because of pasting unless the answer is incorrect.

Comment: If you don't add any actual code or detailed explanation but only show "go look here links" then its "not" an answer. You need to add those links under user comments only.

Comment: no problem dude ... just telling ya how things work on this forum

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate your efforts to improve answers...