# How to Convert Excel File to PDF in Objective - C by programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have excel file and **want to convert in pdf in objective c**.

Try to find out solution by googling but unfortunately can't got any idea.

Can anybody help to me to solve this problem? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with google docs API.

I have implement this
 https://gist.github.com/kinlane/922855

Comment: plz explain in details.

Comment: please check this question.... Hope you find your answere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094341/how-to-convert-doc-xls-ppt-to-pdf-using-objective-c