# How to get the Page count of doc/docx file which is shown in the UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I want to divide the word file into number of pages and stores into an array and when it required I wanted to show that specific page in to `UIWebView`. I have done the same thing for PPT but not able to do for word file. Here is my code for PPT.

(1) Use `UIWebView` to display the content of the PPT. The well formed (!) HTML allows you to parse it. Get the html using

```
NSString *htmlContent = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

(2) Count the number of div class = 'slide to get the slide count

(3) You need to parse the HTML to get the styles and div using the below code

(4) Get all the styles

```
- (NSString *)getStyles:(int)slideCount forView:(UIWebView *)view {

    NSString *getElementByTag = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *allStyles = [[NSString alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
        getElementByTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('style')[%d].innerHTML", i];
        NSString *style =  [[view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:getElementByTag] stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
        allStyles = [allStyles stringByAppendingString:style];
    }

    allStyles = [@"<style type='text/css'>" stringByAppendingString: allStyles];

    return [allStyles stringByAppendingString:@"</style>"];
}
```

(5) Concatenate all the styles from step 5 with div tag content. Define a `NSMutableArray` variable to to store all slides with styles for future reference. Define `NSMutableArray` *slides to store all the slides

```
- (void)makeSlides:(int)slideCount forView:(UIWebView *)view {

    self.slides = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
        NSString *slideBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByClassName('slide')[%d].innerHTML", i];
        NSString *div = [view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:slideBody];

        NSString *slide = [self.slideStyles stringByAppendingString:div];
        [self.slides addObject:slide];
    }
}
```

Like that i want to do the same thing for word document. Please do needful for me.

I have take reference of this link.
[IOS library to convert powerpoint presentations into images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971969/ios-library-to-convert-powerpoint-presentations-into-images/18129059#18129059%E2%80%8B)